# LinkedIn api calls using .bat file

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I just recently setup php api calls to share on LinkedIn company pages and is working well when I run the script, however when I include the script in a .bat file. It does not work. I have done exactly the same thing for the twitter api and that works perfectly so I know that there is no issue with the way I am doing it. I have only made a few calls so no throttle issue and in between I have tested the scipt and it does work.

The only thing that may be a problem would be that the access token is passed in the headers for LinkedIn and the .bat file is not making a http request as I have 
C:\php7\php.exe -f C:\path_to_file.php. So just wondering whether there is a way I could do this. I use the .bat files to setup scheduled tasks to automate posts.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this was to call a php file that then used curl to run the api call.